# generating flask route from class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

i am trying to generate Flask route using a basic DI i.e mapping methods as route handlers, i am a total beginner at Flask so mind my basic skills

```
class myClass():

    def __init__(self):
        self.dbConnObj = DbToolsMySql('someconnection', 'slave')
        self.dbConnObj.connect()
        self.blueprint = Blueprint('myClass', __name__)
        self.blueprint.add_url_rule('/my_method', view_func=self.my_method)

    def my_method(self, event):
        retun "hello"
```

and then in my handler file

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
from src.app.services.myClassimport myClass


app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(myClass.blueprint)

if __name__ == "main":
    app.run()
```

Quite simple ehh???? but not working... i am getting following message

> Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you
> entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: You misspelled **return** as *retun* in `my_method`. Also, which URL are you visiting that you're getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

typically you add routes to the Flask app with decorators like so:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/some-endpoint')
def some_endpoint_handler():
   # do something
   pass
```

Or you can add without a decorator like so:

```
def some_endpoint_handler():
   # do something
   pass

app = Flask(__name__)

app.route('/some-endpoint', methods=['GET'])(some_endpoint_handler)
```

So in your scenario, you can pass the app.route call to your myClass object and set the route like this:

```
class myClass():

    def __init__(self, router):
        self.dbConnObj = DbToolsMySql('someconnection', 'slave')
        self.dbConnObj.connect()
        self.blueprint = Blueprint('myClass', __name__)
        #self.blueprint.add_url_rule('/my_method', view_func=self.my_method)
        router('/my_method', ['GET'])(self.my_method)

    def my_method(self, event):
        retun "hello"

myObj = myClass( app.route )
```

or, invert the dependency:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route(myClass.blueprint.some_endpoint_string)
def some_endpoint_handler():
   myClass.blueprint.call_some_endpoint_handler()
   pass

if __name__ == "main":
    app.run()
```

Comment: `@app.route(myClass.blueprint.some_endpoint_string)`  can you explain this part to me pelase?

Comment: it's a prop in your Blueprint class that represents the endpoint the frontend is hitting. In your example, you'd set self.blueprint.some_endpoint_string = '/my_method'. That string is then passed to the app.route decorator function. It should be noted myClass.blueprint needs to be instantiated BEFORE you invoke that app.route decorator